# migrate acralyzer with database to cloud - AWS

Tags: couchdb, acra

I have an acralyzer instance, which obviously runs with a couchdb.
I need to move this setup to a diff machine at cloud - say need to move it along with data to AWS, what strategy should i follow other than the Xcopy (which i won't like to do) approach.

Comment: is both the instance on AWS ?? or one on premise and other on AWS ??

Comment: the current one is at azure, I wanted to migrate it to AWS; but no problem now, I am working now with Microsoft :) , the issue was also resolved.

Comment: Great to hear ! If possible can you update the answer to this question. Would be helpful to others